# I can't switch from Blender render to Cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files

I'm having problems by switching rendering. The problem is that Cycles render doesn't appear in the top. There's only Blender Render and Blender Game.

Also when I run the program, a windows opens up in the user preferences and everything that was before is gone. I don't know if I did something to my PC or Blender files.

Comment: Cycles is an addon, built-in. Make sure it's enabled 

Answer (score 1):

make sure that cycles is enabled in your add-on panel in your user preferences. also it might help if you upload your blend file with this problem.